# Stop camera Movement at a wall (or obstacle)

Tags: c++, c, opengl, camera, glut

I just learned a bit GLUT, already set up a moveable camera, lighting & made a `class` containing some 3D forms.

But now I want the camera to not be able to go through such objects. Is there any type of `OpenGL` or `glut` command with which I can check whether there's an obstacle at a specific point or at the actual camera position?

Comment: Are you using gluLookAt to move your camera?

Comment: no, i'm already able to move the cam with the maouse & the Keyboard, i want the motion of the camera to _Stop_ when theres e.g. a Cube drawn at the current camera's postion, so that the cam Won't be able to move through the cube.

Comment: As far as I know, this is a difficult subject and I myself have no experience of it yet, I'm learning myself. You could use a simple brute force approach if your problem is not complex enough. This could be helpful:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/collision_detection/17005/
And:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/tips-for-writing-3d-collision-detection-with-opengl

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL is a rasterizer API, it doesn't check or handle collisions for you. Common ways to detect collisions are bounding boxes or bounding spheres. You can treat your camera position as a point and check if it's inside the obstacle's bounding volume. To get the bounding sphere's radius, you must loop through every vertex in the model and store the distance to its center. You only need to do this looping once, not every frame.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is not a scene graph, which means it doesn't have any sort of internal representation of a scene, or world. OpenGL is a drawing API, it just draws points, lines and triangles on a framebuffer, one at a time – and then forgets about them.

Hence OpenGL will not do collision detection for you. It *is* possible to implement a collision detection system using OpenGL, but this is something your program does then, not OpenGL.

Comment: I solved my problem by using a a big 3-dimensional bool-array (20000^3) which stores information where the blocks are.. it's working very well altough it's ver big, because it will never read the whole array at once, only a few (exactly 6) elements every frame :D

Comment: @AndiFaust: Why not simply test for collisions with your regular scene geometry? It's not very difficult and much more efficient for sure.

Comment: I have no idea how i should do that... Could you explain it to me?

Comment: There's an excellent book about the topic: http://realtimecollisiondetection.net